# Why are not my subscriptions not disposed even though disposebag is hooked and my view is dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, dispose

I recently noticed that none of my `subscriptions` are actually `disposed` even though I hook `.disposed(by: disposeBag)`. Even if I leave the `view` or `dismiss` the `modal` completely, the `subscriptions` refuse to `dispose`.

I have my `views` in a `tabBar` which keeps the `subscriptions` alive I suppose, even though I leave the `view`, but even so, this `tabBar` is in a `modal` and when the `modal` is `dismissed` shouldn't the `subscriptions` `dispose` on their own accord?

One way around this is to manually `dispose` all `subscriptions` on `viewWillDisappear`, but I would still like to know why this issue persists.

```
private func noErrorText() {
    viewModel.activeErrorContent.debug("--debugNoErrorText").subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] cells in
        self?.noErrorView.isHidden = !cells.isEmpty 
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Which gives the output:

> > 2022-03-25 04:26:55.219: --debugNoErrorText -> subscribed
> > 2022-03-25 04:26:55.219: --debugNoErrorText -> Event next([])

Let me know if there is anything else that I should provide or explain.

***EDIT***
In response to the comments:

The disposeBag is in a `superClass` and my `subscriptions` and `disposed(by:)` are in a `subClass`. Not sure if that's relevant.

```
final class TechnicianDashboardViewController: BaseViewController {...
```

Here are my `subscriptions`:

If I understand it correctly with `strong` references, then `self.disposeBag` in the first snippet creates a strong reference to the `subView`.

```
extension TechnicianDashboardViewController: PinCodeViewControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate {
    func completed(currentPin: String?, newPin: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.resetWithOverlay(pin: newPin)
                .subscribe().disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
        }
    }
}
```

Then there are these as well. All use the same `disposeBag`. None of them are `disposed`.

```
private func noErrorText() {
        viewModel.activeErrorContent.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] cells in
            self?.noErrorView.isHidden = !cells.isEmpty
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
    
private func getErrors() {
    viewModel.activeErrorContent.bind(to: activeErrorTableView.rx
                                            .items(cellIdentifier: ErrorsTableViewCell.identifier,
                                                   cellType: ErrorsTableViewCell.self)) { row, data, cell in
                                                       cell.rowService = row
                                                       cell.viewModel = data
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
    
private func getEvents() {
    viewModel.activeEventContent.bind(to: activeEventTableView.rx
                                            .items(cellIdentifier: EventStatusTableViewCell.identifier,
                                                   cellType: EventStatusTableViewCell.self)) { row, data, cell in
                                                       cell.viewModel = data
                                                       cell.rowService = row
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Comment: When the objects that have a strong reference to the dispose bag deinit, the dispose bag *will* dispose the subscriptions. Which objects have a strong reference to your dispose bag?

Comment: @DanielT. Ah, ok. When you say "objects that have a strong reference to the disposebag", do you mean all subscriptions that use .disposed(by: disposeBag)? Or how do I know what objects have a strong reference? Is there a way to check that? Could you elaborate a bit? :)

Comment: The `disposeBag` is a property of some class. Maybe you passed it to some other objects? No the `.disposed(by: disposeBag)` does not create a strong reference.

Comment: @DanielT. Then setting the disposeBag as weak could be a valid solution?

Comment: No, that would be a horrible idea. Show the code or answer my question. Which objects have a strong reference to your dispose bag?

Comment: @DanielT. Ok, so I updated my answer above. I guess the first part with self.disposeBag creates a strong reference, is that correct?

Comment: No, that doesn't create a strong reference. Based on what you have shown so far (assuming all the code you have shown is in the view controller,) when `TechnicianDashboardViewController` deinits, all the subscriptions would be disposed. Is your view controller deinit-ing?

Comment: So I put a print in `deinit` in `TechnicianDashboardViewController` and it triggers first thing, even before `viewDidLoad`. That doesn't seem right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the cause and solution to why the `subscriptions` don't dispose, much thanks to @Daniel T. I'll write the answer here in case someone have a similar problem.

So basically I added a `print` to `deinit` like this:

```
deinit {
    print("-- DEINIT")
}
```

And it turns out that it's not triggered at all (Well, they are triggered right at the start before anything is loaded, but not when you exit the `view` and I think this is because of the `views` being in a `tabBar controller`, but that's another topic). And this goes for several `views`. This means that the `subscriptions` aren't `disposed`, because that happens in the `deinit`.

So the next question is, why isn't `deinit` triggered. That is because there's a `memory leak` preventing the `ARC` to release the reference to the `view`. The memory leak can be caused by different things, but for most of the time it's because you forget to add `[weak self]` to a closure. If you just forget it at a single place, you can block `deinit` from triggering. In my case, my mistakes were often "hidden" in the `super class`, making it less obvious.

So, fixing the `memory leak` so that `deinit` trigger, will then `dispose` your `subscriptions` like normal, preventing even further `memory leaks`.